# Generic message for Low Quality Answers

Tags: discussion, answers, moderation

Answers on this site can be a little weak at times, so I have begun to downvote the inappropriate ones for:

- Lacking Citations.
- Being to short (1-3 sentences long, I haven't done this yet, but may implement it after input).
- Not explaining themselves.

We all know what a [good quality answer](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1117/how-can-we-improve-answer-quality) is supposed to be and if we don't it's are own fault. Instead of writing a new message every time we see a low quality answer maybe we can come up with a generic message that addresses them and sends them to proper resources on the site to learn. This would:

- Stop the need for repeated downvotes
- Increase the quality of the site
- Increase user experience

So what to say (ultimately it would be user picked, but I have began):

- For Citations:

  > Hello Generic User, it appears as if your post quotes/uses a source from a unidentifiable source. Could you explain where you got it from or link the source appropriately. Thank You.
- Being to Short:

  > Hello Generic User, your post is kind of short could you add some more details and explanation so we can better understand your solution. Thank You.
- Not explaining themselves:

  > Hello Generic User I read your answer and I am having trouble understanding what you propose, could you explain why this solution would work. Thank You.

I have stopped my Quality Control journey to come up with a better solution for this problem. The post would be linked to the Help Center and other resources, but this is the rough draft. I thought this was pertinent, but I will be working on(if someone doesn't beat me to it) a Meta Post about Answer Control.

So what do you think?

Comment: citations? Not necessary for a hack. I wouldn't assume that others have tried it. Being too short isn't a problem, so long as it gives and properly explains the hack.

Comment: Also, once we create a meta post about answer scope, similarly to what we're working on with questions, then will be a better time to implement any changes on-site.

Comment: I'll just drop a reference to the pro forma comments here, since they might help you in your battle for QC: http://stackapps.com/questions/2116

Comment: @J.Musser If I went on the site and picked 2 random questions, the answers not be quality enough for me to want to come back. I would go to other sites and abandon this endeavour, because the answers wouldn't be anything special to me. This site needs to be the best and most quality LifeHack site, this means adding length and citations. We all need to be on the same page.

Answer (score 4):

On [pets.SE](https://pets.stackexchange.com/) Matt S. posted a generic Meta Question [Why is my answer being down-voted or ignored?](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/774/why-is-my-answer-being-down-voted-or-ignored) Then he and others provided detailed answers to common issues.  This has proved to be fairly effective at simplifying how to address low quality answers from new users.

Answer (score 2):

If you see a low quality post, flag it as VLQ (ssh, I have short answers too, gonna improve them ;) ) or Not An Answer.

The posts flagged with VLQ flags or short ones are pushed to the Low Quality review queue, where its possible for reviewers to choose some reasons like "NAA, but comment", "new question", "thank you answer", etc.

I doubt if SE staff will include some specific deletion reasons for this site, because doesn't do it for another sites (there were already requests).

So, I **doubt that it will be implemented**. You can make a list of those messages for you, and when reviewing Low Quality answers or flagging them, you can add one of those comments.

Comment: Some answers aren't very bad and I want to spread the message for quality control, flagging does not seem like that option.

Comment: @ili Yep, right, but there is a flag for such answers anyway. Choose Not An Answer flag. Anyway, I doubt that any template messages for flags or template comments will be for specific site.

Comment: So what is your advice if a post is not very low quality or not a answer, then what should I do? Because the post just needs expansion,  citations or an explanation.

Comment: @ili Comment + downvote if nothing else wrong (only length). But anyway, if the answer is too short, or link only, I flag it as not an answer. Also if plagiarism, flag it with "other" and explain that the content is plagiarized.